# How to login into beaglebone black remotely

Tags: linux, remote-access, beagleboneblack

I have my beaglebone black running stock Angstrom Linux and is connected to ethernet at my home. I can login from any PC connected to my home network using SSH. I would like to know how can I login from another network, say I am at my office and I am connected to internet. I want to login into my beaglebone black which is connected to internet at my Home. How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a public IP address, that is given to you by your Internet operator. This public IP however will be different than the IP of your Beagle in your local network.

To login to your Beagle from the Internet, you need to connect to your public IP address, and need to add port forwarding to your router, so that port `22`, which is the socket port that is used by `ssh`, is forwarded from your public IP to your local IP.

So, you need to login to your router management console, and go to "port forwarding" options, and select to forward TCP/IP connections to port 22 be forwarded to your Beagle IP. For this to work longer term, you should set static IP address to your Beagle, otherwise if your board stays offline for long time, the DHCP server on your router will probably assign different IP at some point, and the forwarding would need to be setup again.

There is a good guide on the static IP address setting in Beagle/Angstrom here: http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/

One more thing: Since your operator will also assign different public IP for you from time to time, you might want to have some kind of Dynamic DNS service in use. With this kind of service, you can create your "custom" DNS address (for example `user3180454.no-ip.com`), that will always point to your Public IP address to which you can create ssh connection (the service will require some method to keep this IP address up to date, you will see instructions on how to do it from the service you use).

Couple services like this:

http://no-ip.com/

http://freedns.afraid.org/

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to try out the Weaved connection service installer for BeagleBone Black.  I'm using it to connect:

SSH on port 22
BBB web server on port 80
tightVNC server on port 5901
Shell in a Box on port 4200
Apache web server on port 8080

See:

https://developer.weaved.com/portal/members/betabeagle.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are:

- Connecting to from a BeagleBoard via USB Ethernet
- from Mac Air running Mavericks & connected to web via Wifi

I found this very helpful:

http://makezine.com/2012/07/16/use-your-mac-laptop-as-a-wireless-proxy-for-raspberry-pi/

In short >> install/run a proxy server (with Squidman) & your life will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I thought I'd suggest another option. I use TeamViewer (https://www.teamviewer.com) to connect to my work/home computers. You could use something like this to connect to your home computer from the office. Once connected to your home computer, you could then do whatever you need to do on your home network. No port forwarding required.